# Android WebView (WebChromeClient) Speech Synthesis Undefined

Tags: javascript, html, webview, text-to-speech, chromium

I'm trying to use Web Speech Synthesis API in an Android WebView that I've set as a WebChromeClient. However when I inspect the page and run the following command
`console.log('speechSynthesis' in window, 'webkitSpeechRecognition' in window, 'speechRecognition' in window);` each is returned as false, false, false.

If I inspect a page using Chrome on Android then it returns true, true, false.

The user agent on via the Chrome App shows as:

> "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 8.1.0; Pixel 2 XL Build/OPM1.171019.018)
>   AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/64.0.3282.137 Mobile
>   Safari/537.36"

and the Chrome WebView shows as:

> "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 8.1.0; Pixel 2 XL Build/OPM1.171019.018;
>   wv) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0
>   Chrome/64.0.3282.137 Mobile Safari/537.36"

The Chrome version is exactly the same, but the speechSynthesis is not in the window.

I've enabled the following settings on the webview:

```
    webViewSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webViewSettings.setAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs(true);
    webViewSettings.setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);
    webViewSettings.setAllowContentAccess(true);
    webViewSettings.setAllowFileAccess(true);
    webViewSettings.setDatabaseEnabled(true);
    webViewSettings.setMediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture(false);
```

Thanks

Comment: I don't know what's up with Android. Everything seems difficult. I have been searching all day but couldn't find anything. As I understand, this would work if the webview would render with the chrome renderer(can't find how to do it)

Comment: Please see: https://issues.chromium.org/issues/40417848

Answer (score 0):

The code is correct but you need to change the code from `webViewSettings` to `webview.getSettings()`